# header buttons are square rather than rounded

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I was expecting my buttons in the header to be rounded, but instead they are coming out square.  See the home button in the screenshot:

[image]

My CSS:

```
#main {
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow: visible;
   white-space: normal;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-header .ui-title {
    overflow: visible !important; 
}
.ui-header {
    min-height: 40px;
}
```

The snipped of html declaring the header:

```
  <div data-role="page" id="settings">
       <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
          <a href="#home"  data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
          <h1>App</h1>
       </div>
       ...
```

I was expecting to see buttons round similar to these:

[image]

Any pointers appreciated ...

Comment: It looks fine on Chrome, Firefox and IE (http://jsfiddle.net/d5374gbo/), what browser are you testing?

Comment: I'm running it on an android 4.4.4 physical device using cordova, so it will be wrapping webkit I believe.

Comment: If you open the site on Firefox/Chrome, does the link look squared or rounded?

Comment: If I open the link in Chrome on the device, the button looks rounded.

Comment: With jQM 1.4.x try using the classes directly instead of data attributes: <a href="#home"  class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext">Home</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to this line in my code:

```
$('a').buttonMarkup({ corners: false });
```

Removing that fixed the problem :$

Answer (score 0):

For rounded corners, I'd expect something like:

```
#home {
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Unfortunately, this is also something that varies between implementation of the CSS, so if this doesn't work, please provide more info on versions of tools you use.